# how to use a for loop vs a while loop in this code

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I'm learning python thru treehouse and am very green so please take this with a grain of salt.  I made this work with a while loop, but think it would make much more sense as a for loop, as the number of times it loops is set by the length of the word. The goal is to make the first half of any word lowercase, and the second half uppercase.  Im sure this is super basic, but i spent forever trying to make it happen, but had major problems i couldn't figure out due to the list vs string issue...  Any thoughts would be very appreciated!
Thanks! Brian (see below code)

```
def sillycase(word1):
    half = int(len(word1)/2)
    word1 = list(word1)
    counter = 0
    while True:
      if counter < half:
        word1[counter] = word1[counter].lower()
      elif counter >= len(word1):
        break
      else:
        word1[counter] = word1[counter].upper()
      counter += 1

    word1 = "".join(word1[:])

    print(word1)
    return word1
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can actually do it simply without using any loop by slicing the first half of the input string and converting it to lowercase and converting the other half to uppercase:

```
def sillycase(word1):
    half_len=int(len(word1)/2)
    temp1=word1.lower()[:half_len]
    temp2=word1[half_len::].upper()
    final_string= temp1+temp2
    return final_string
```